# PL/SQL Oracle ROWTYPE Access like array

Tags: oracle, plsql, rowtype

I have some PL/SQL code:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_data IS
    SELECT *
    FROM table;
    TYPE bulk_collect IS TABLE OF c_data%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    l_tab bulk_collect;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_data
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab LIMIT 1000;
    EXIT WHEN l_tab.count = 0;

    -- Process contents of collection here.
    --Insert into tt_kust values l_tab;
      FOR indx IN 1 .. l_tab.COUNT 
          LOOP
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab(indx).col_name);
          END LOOP;
      END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_data;
END;
```

This works fine!
But when I try to access the columns of 'l_tab' like this:

```
FOR indx IN 1 .. l_tab.COUNT 
    LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab(indx)['col_name']);
    END LOOP;
```

it does not work! Is there a way to access the 'l_tab' like an array without the 'dot' notation?
I want to do because I want to use this pl/sql code for more than one table, so it must be dynamic. 
So later in the FOR LOOP I want to do something like this:

```
FOR indx IN 1 .. l_tab.COUNT 
        LOOP
             upt_stmt := 'update table set colname= :col1, colname=:col2, ...
               where pkcolname = :pkcolname ;
         execute immediate upt_stmt using l_tab(indx)['col_name'],l_tab(indx)['col_name2'], ....;
        END LOOP;
```

Comment: You can use dynamic sql with 'dot' notation. Why is it a problem? `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_tab(indx).'||col_name)`

Comment: Realistically, no.  In order to have a local variable `l_tab`, the compiler would need to know the definition of the collection at compile time.  If you are saying that you won't know until runtime what fields are in your record type than the declaration of `l_tab` and, realistically, the declaration of the type of `l_tab` would need to be done in a dynamic PL/SQL block. That's possible.  But it is complicated.  I'd strongly suggest looking at what you're trying to accomplish to see if there is a better way.

Comment: @Tatiana, its not working the output is the following string: 'l_tab(indx).col_name', but I want to access the value of the column!

Comment: @Zar `execute immediate 'select l_tab(indx).'||col_name||' from dual'  into p_val` - you will have value in p_val variable

Comment: Have a look at [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF), esp. functions `DEFINE_COLUMN` and `COLUMN_VALUE`. However, as mentioned by Justin check carefully if you really need all this dynamic stuff.

Comment: @Tatiana - `l_tab` and `indx` will be out of scope of the SQL being run?

Comment: @AlexPoole not exactly understand what do you mean